# Having users su/sudo in Linux based on Active Directory group when using pam_winbind

Tags: linux, active-directory, sudo, opensuse, su

I'm using openSUSE 11.4 which has Active Directory configuration built-in to Yast (which does all the pam_winbind, Kerberos, nss, Samba-client stuff for you) and I can successfully authenticate against my AD domain.

I created an AD group called LinuxAdmins and I'd like to have a way for people in that group to either be able to su on certain Linux servers without the root password or sudo on those machines using their own passwords.

The way openSUSE configures AD, it sets the username with the domain prefixed. So my username would be MYDOMAN\djsumdog. If I try adding either of the following lines to the sudoers file, I still can't sudo with my user. I keep getting "MYDOMAIN\djsumdog is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported." I've tried both single and double slashes for the user and group names.

```
%MYDOMAIN\LinuxAdmins ALL=(ALL) ALL
MYDOMAIN\djsumdog ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

I know on my Gentoo box, the following line in /etc/pam.d/su allows users in the wheel group to su without a password:

```
auth       sufficient   pam_wheel.so use_uid trust
```

But this doesn't seem to work in openSUSE (even with local users), much less AD users. I tried using the pam_winbind.so module as well:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth     sufficient     pam_rootok.so
auth     include        common-auth
auth     sufficient     pam_winbind.so require_membership_of=MYDOMAIN\\LinuxAdmins
account  sufficient     pam_rootok.so
account  include        common-account
password include        common-password
session  include        common-session
session  optional       pam_xauth.so
```

But I don't think that will work as the require_membership_of parameter seems to be for the primary authentication against the entire machine.

I know sudo with the user's password is more secure, but I would happy if I could get either su or sudo working by validating the user against his or her AD group.

Comment: When you run "id djsumdog", what format do the returned group names look like? In particular, I know some Samba setups replace the backslash with a plus-sign.

Comment: That got it! The case for my AD group was wrong (it was all lowercase and I was using mixed case). Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per Hadyman5's comment, I ran the following:

```
 id MYDOMAIN\\djsumdog
```

...and saw that my group was actually MYDOMAIN\linuxadmins, **all lower case**. I then added the following to my sudo configuration:

```
%MYDOMAIN\\linuxadmins ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

And sudo works fine now with the users in that group.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have a space, like I did, in the group, you need to add a backslash before the space:  %MYDOMAIN\\domain\ admins ALL=(ALL) ALL

Answer (score 0):

Using the directions to add a centos 7 box to my 2012r2 domain located [Here](http://www.hexblot.com/blog/centos-7-active-directory-and-samba), I was able to add to my domain.  Adding a AD group to sudoers required me to format the group as `%GroupName@DOMAIN ALL=(ALL) ALL` and it worked.